# Finding median in merged array of two sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, median

Assume we have 2 sorted arrays of integers with sizes of n and m. What is the best way to find median of all `m + n` numbers?

It's easy to do this with `log(n) * log(m)` complexity. But i want to solve this problem in `log(n) + log(m)` time. So is there any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: I can't find a great duplicate, but there are dozens of [easily-findable](https://www.google.com/search?q=median+of+2+sorted+arrays) posts about this on [so] and elsewhere, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790467/median-of-two-sorted-arrays) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222934/median-of-2-sorted-arrays-of-different-lengths). Shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**

The key point of this problem is to ignore half part of A and B each step recursively by comparing the median of remaining A and B:

```
if (aMid < bMid) Keep [aMid  +1 ... n] and [bLeft ... m]    
else Keep [bMid + 1 ... m] and [aLeft ... n]
// where n and m are the length of array A and B
```

As the following: time complexity is `O(log(m + n))`

```
public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] A, int[] B) {
    int m = A.length, n = B.length;
    int l = (m + n + 1) / 2;
    int r = (m + n + 2) / 2;
    return (getkth(A, 0, B, 0, l) + getkth(A, 0, B, 0, r)) / 2.0;
}

public double getkth(int[] A, int aStart, int[] B, int bStart, int k) {
    if (aStart > A.length - 1) return B[bStart + k - 1];            
    if (bStart > B.length - 1) return A[aStart + k - 1];                
    if (k == 1) return Math.min(A[aStart], B[bStart]);

    int aMid = Integer.MAX_VALUE, bMid = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (aStart + k/2 - 1 < A.length) aMid = A[aStart + k/2 - 1]; 
    if (bStart + k/2 - 1 < B.length) bMid = B[bStart + k/2 - 1];        

    if (aMid < bMid) 
        return getkth(A, aStart + k / 2, B, bStart, k - k / 2); // Check: aRight + bLeft 
    else 
        return getkth(A, aStart, B, bStart + k / 2, k - k / 2); // Check: bRight + aLeft
}
```

Hope it helps! Let me know if you need more explanation on any part.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a very good solution I found in Java on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222934/median-of-2-sorted-arrays-of-different-lengths) It's a method of finding the K and K+1 smallest items in the two arrays where K is the center of the merged array.

If you have a function for finding the Kth item of two arrays then finding the median of the two is easy;

1. Calculate the weighted average of the Kth and Kth+1 items of X and Y

But then you'll need a way to find the Kth item of two lists; (remember we're one indexing now)

1. If X contains zero items then the Kth smallest item of X and Y is the Kth smallest item of Y
2. Otherwise if K == 2 then the second smallest item of X and Y is the smallest of the smallest items of X and Y (min(X[0], Y[0]))
3. Otherwise;

   i. Let A be min(length(X), K / 2)

   ii. Let B be min(length(Y), K / 2)

   iii. If the X[A] > Y[B] then recurse from step 1. with X, Y' with all elements of Y from B to the end of Y and K' = K - B, otherwise recurse with X' with all elements of X from A to the end of X, Y and K' = K - A

If I find the time tomorrow I will verify that this algorithm works in Python as stated and provide the example source code, it may have some off-by-one errors as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Take the median element in list A and call it a. Compare a to the center elements in list B. Lets call them b1 and b2 (if B has odd length then exactly where you split b depends on your definition of the median of an even length list, but the procedure is almost identical regardless). if b1≤a≤b2 then a is the median of the merged array. This can be done in constant time since it requires exactly two comparisons.

If a is greater than b2 then we add the top half of A to the top of B and repeat. B will no longer be sorted, but it doesn't matter. If a is less than b1 then we add the bottom half of A to the bottom of B and repeat. These will iterate log(n) times at most (if the median is found sooner then stop, of course).

It is possible that this will not find the median. If this is the case then the median is in B. If so, perform the same algorithm with A and B reversed. This will require log(m) iterations. In total you will have performed at most 2*(log(n)+log(m)) iterations of a constant time operation, so you have solved the problem in order log(n)+log(m) time.

This is essentially the same answer as was given by iehrlich, but written out more explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this can be done. Given two arrays, `A` and `B`, in the worst-case scenario you have to first perform a binary search in `A`, and then, if it fails, binary search in `B` looking for the median. On each step of a binary search, you check if the current element is actually a median of a merged `A+B` array. Such check takes constant time.

Let's see why such check is constant. For simplicity, let's assume that `|A| + |B|` is an odd number, and that all numbers in both arrays are different. You can remove these restrictions later by applying the usual median definition approach (i.e., how to calculate the median of an array containing duplicates, or of an array with even length). Anyway, given that, we know for sure, that in the merged array there will be `(|A| + |B| - 1) / 2` elements to the right and to the left of an actual median. In the process of a binary search in `A`, we know the index of current element `x` in array `A` (let it be `i`). Now, if `x` satisfies the condition `B[j] < x < B[j+1]`, where `i + j == (|A| + |B| - 1) / 2`, then `x` is your median.

The overall complexity is `O(log(max(|A|, |B|))` time and `O(1)` memory.

Comment: Some comments regarding downvotes are highly appreciated.

Comment: Your algorithm seems to be malformed, I can't tell if it will actually return the median of A+B or not

Comment: @JacaByte this is not the definition of "malformed". Counter-example is.

Comment: Now I know what's wrong with your answer, it's a test to check if a number is the median but never provides a clear way of _finding_ that number, which is what OP asked for. You also write off the cases where the length of A+B is even and A+B contain duplicates as trivial, but in realty they are not.

Comment: @JacaByte if the criteria is satisfied on the first pass (as in my answer), the median is `A[i]`. If it is satisfied on the second pass, the median is `B[i]`.

Comment: @JacaByte in realty they are. Wikipedia (or any other trustful source defining what median is) will be a nice starting point for clarifying these questions.